# About Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects module in Qt 6.x

Tags: qt, qml

How can I use Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects module in Qt6.3 or later without purchasing the commercial license, since it requires the additional installation of QtShaderTools, which is under a commercial license?
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJpXa.jpg)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JszBg.jpg)

Is there an open-source alternative to Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects?
Or how to use Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects to avoide commercial license?

Comment: It's also available under GPL v3 or GPL v2 free sw licenses https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtshadertools-index.html.